# Awk: Splitting file on nth occurence of delimiter, wrong first split file

Tags: bash, awk

I want to split a text file like the one pasted below (sorry for the length), on every n occurence  of ">". For example, every 2nd occurrence of ">", but I need to able able to change that number.

test_split.txt:

```
>eeefkdfn
a
a
a
>c 4ufjdhf
b
b
b
b
>
c
c
> c
d
d
d
d
d
>3
>cr
>c3
e
e
e
e
e
> 5
f
f
f
f
>cr
g
g
g
g
> cr dkjfddf
h
h
h
h
```

So I want to have output files this these (only showing the first two):

file_1.txt:

```
>eeefkdfn
a
a
a
>c 4ufjdhf
b
b
b
b
```

file_2.txt:

```
>
c
c
> c
d
d
d
d
d
```

etc.

Question:

I have been trying to achieve that result using this awk command:

```
awk '/^>/ {n++} { file = sprintf("file_%s.txt", int(n/2)); print >> file; }' < test_split.txt
```

And instead of the desired result, I am getting correct output (split) files, except for the first one, which only contains one occurence of ">" (instead of two), like this:

cat test_0.txt

```
>eeefkdfn
a
a
a
```

cat test_1.txt

```
>chr1 4ufjdhf
b
b
b
b
>
c
c
```

Any idea why that is? Thank you!

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand what are you trying to achieve and what your issue is. May I suggest you to kindly re-phrase your question with a little bit of consolidation and clearly highlight the "Problem-part" and the "Question-part", which will make it easier for all of us to understand and try to help you with the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Edited my post a bit, I hope it is clearer! If not let me know what is missing

Comment: Swap the order of your increment and print sections.  You are incrementing before the first section.

Comment: @stark can you give an example? I am not sure what you mean

Comment: You need to think about your math.  First you do 1/2 which will be zero, but when it increments again to 2/2 you are already changing the name of the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems more simple:

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1}/^>/{cont++}cont==3{i++;cont=1}{print > "file_"i".txt"} file
```

Will gives you the expected result:

```
$ cat file_1.txt
>eeefkdfn
a
a
a
>c 4ufjdhf
b
b
b
b

$ cat file_2.txt
>
c
c
> c
d
d
d
d
d
```

**Explanation**

`BEGIN{i=1}`: File counter initialization.

`/^>/{cont++}`: To count every `>` found.

`cont==3{i++;cont=1}`: To increase the file counter and initialize the cont var every third appearance of the `>` char which becomes first again.

`{print > "file_"i".txt"}`: Direct the output to the expected file.

Comment: When input is large it will leave many unclosed file handles.

Comment: @anubhava What do you mean by unclosed file handles (tried looking it up but didn't find much)

Comment: (I am still a beginner) can you explain the cont==3{i++;cont=1} part please? Why ==3? Thanks!

Comment: shorten this `awk -vn=2 '/^>/{i++}{print > "file_" (int((i-1)/n)+1) ".txt"}' file`

Comment: @arielle: Every time you do `> afile` it opens up a file handle for writing. If we create large no of files and don't close these files inside `awk` it is like a memory leak. That's the reason I have added calls to `close(file)` in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk for dynamic control over number `n` where file will be split on `nth` occurrence of `>` in input data:

```
awk -v n=2 'function ofile() {
   if (op)
      close(op)
   op = sprintf("file_%d.txt", ++p)
}
BEGIN {
   ofile()
}
/>/ {
   ++i
}
i > n {
   i=1
   ofile()
}
{
   print $0 > op
}
END {
   close(op)
}' file
```

Here is one liner in case you want to copy/paste:

```
awk -v n=2 'function ofile() {if (op) close(op); op = sprintf("file_%d.txt", ++p)} BEGIN{ofile()} />/{++i} i>n{i=1; ofile()} { print $0 > op }' file
```