# Splitting file on nth occurence of delimiter and add content from txt file to every new file

Tags: awk, sed, split

I want to split a >500MB ASCII based text file after ~5000 occurrences of a delimiter ("00I" in may case). I am using the code from (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42302328/14957413)

```
awk -v n=5000 '
   function ofile() {
      if (op) 
         close(op); 
      op = sprintf("file.GES.%d.", ++p)
   } 
   BEGIN{ofile()} 
   /00I/{++i} i>n{i=1; ofile()} 

   { print $0 > op }' 
file
```

**The source file start with around ~1000 lines of variables declarations, that I need to also have in every new file that I create with the snippet from above.**

**Input**

```
//file header
00K
01Filename
02Fieltype
03Date

//00F describes a variable
00F 
0101
02Variable name 1
03text
04length
00F 
0102
02Variable name 2
03number
04length

//content I want split
00I
01Value for first F, e.g. Test
02Value for second F, e.g. 1
//this repeats a couple of 1.000.000 times
00I
01Value for first F, e.g. TestN
02Value for second F, e.g. N
```

**expected output for first to nth file**

```
//Header
00K
01Filename
02Fieltype
03Date

//Variable declaration
00F 
0101
02Variable name 1
03text
04length
00F 
0102
02Variable name 2
03number
04length

//Content
00I
01Value for first F, e.g. Test
02Value for second F, e.g. 1
```

**Two ideas**

1. Extending awk statement to store the first ~1000 lines of the source file in a variable and to append it in every newly generated file.
2. Preparing a separate file with the variable declaration and adding its content to every newly generated file.

**Questions**
What is the best way to achieve the task?
Can it be done by extending the awk expression?
Do I need to run two statements - first the awk and second the sed statement?

Help is very much appreaciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for showing your efforts(keep it up). Could you please do mention samples of input and expected output too in your question(in text form with CODE TAGS) which will give us better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 done. Thanks for the reminder. Hope this helps to better understand the context.

Comment: If you change your question and example to talk about a file of, say, 10 lines being split every, say, 3 occurrences of whatever (i.e. create and show us a [mcve]) then we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by slightly altering @kvantour solution:

```
awk -v n=5000 'function outputFile() {
   
if (output)
      close(output);
   output = sprintf("Filename.%d", ++p);
  
}
BEGIN {
   outputFile();
   h = 0;
}

/00I/ {
   ++i;
}
i > n {
   i=1;
   h=0;
   outputFile();
}
i == 0{
   header = header ORS $0; next;
}
h == 0 && i == 1{
    print header > output;
    h=1;
}

{ 
   print $0 > output;
}
END {
   close(output);
}' PAC_APO.GES
```

So what is happening between **begin** and **end**:

1. Initially set helper variable **h** to 0 (needed to add the header information only once - see bullet 5) in **begin**
2. Incrementing **i**, whenever delimiter found **00I**
3. When **i** grows bigger than the initially set **n=5000** reset **i** and **h** and run **outputFile** function
4. While **i** equals 0 (no delimiter found) collect header information
   in **header** and prevent any other execution with **next**
5. If **h==0** and first **I** found, append **header** to **output** and set **h** to 1 to prevent adding the header information again
6. In any other case, collect **current line $0** in **output**

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk, you can do the following:

```
awk -v n=5000 'BEGIN{RS="\n00I\n"}
               (NR==1){h=$0; next;}
               (i%n==0){close(f); f= "file.GES." (++c); printf "%s",h > f}
               {printf "%s%s", RS, $0 > f; ++i}' file
```

This will create files containing 5000 records.

**How does it work?**

By defining the record separator to be equal to `\n00I\n` `RS="\n00I\n"`, we split the input file `file` in a set of multi-line records which are separated by  `RS`. When awk processes a record, the record `$0` will contain all lines between two `\n00I\n`. When awk reads the first record (`NR==1`) it will store it in the variable `h`. This will contain the header and the variables (unless `RS` is found in one of these blocks). From that point on we start counting the records. Each time we have 5000 records, we create a new file with the name `file.GES.n` where `n` is an incrementing number per file. This is done in the line

```
(i%n==0){close(f); f="file.GES." (++c); printf "%s",h > f}
```

Each time we process a record, we print it to the file and increment the record counter `i` which is used to check if we need a new file or not.

Comment: thanks for your input. Where would I store the file and variable declaration in your example? I get how the splitting works, but am not really sure if every file would start with the 00K and 00F part from the sample data.

Comment: @AlexR The above is very simple, it will split purely on finding the string `\n00I\n`. So the first record will contain the header and the variables, all other records will be as they are. There is nothing that checks for 00K or 00F and your question also does not mention anything about it.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry that my example was poorly, but I need the 00k and 00F information in the beginning of every file. The code listed in the example already does the splitting. It is indeed very similar to your example.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. In my code, the header as well as the variable declarations are all incorporated in the first record and stored in `h`. The code above includes `h` in every single file. So all files should have the variable declaration in it (unless `00I` can appear in the variable declarations)

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on how you "store" the header part. I don't understand it from your code. Additionally, running it doesn't create any output for me (using Mac Terminal).

Comment: @AlexR This is the line `(NR==1){h=$0; next;}`

Comment: @AlexR I've added some explanation.

Comment: Ok. this lines stores the first 1k lines of the source files and  in ```printf "%s",h > f}```we use it to append it to every file generated. Correct? Still, for me your code doesn't create any file.

Comment: The filenames are `input_file.n`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Indeed very helpful. Maybe I get the problem. The file does not start with an 00I statement. It starts with the 00K, followed by multiple 00F sections. The first 00I appears after the declaration part.

Comment: @AlexR that is the first record which will be stored in `h`

Comment: Just to be sure. Files will be created in the folder that the Terminal points to, correct?

Comment: @AlexR, I've updated it so that files will now be created in the directory you run it and they will have the name `file.GES.n`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Found a working solution and posted an updated answer.