# Split large text file by nth (10000th) occurrence by two forward slashes

Tags: awk, split

I am attempting to split a large file in half (or more, files sizes do not need to be equal) using the n-th occurrence of two forward slashes. I would like to keep the two forward slashes at the end of the first split file. I have tried implementing [Search pattern containing forward slash using AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789643/search-pattern-containing-forward-slash-using-awk) in conjunction with [Awk: Splitting file on nth occurence of delimiter, wrong first split file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301745/awk-splitting-file-on-nth-occurence-of-delimiter-wrong-first-split-file) to receive

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1}/^>/{cont++}cont==10000{i++;cont=1}{print > "file_"i".txt"}' Pfam-A.hmm

### Error Code Here
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    BEGIN{i=1}/^>/{cont++}cont==300{i++;cont=1}{print > >>>  "file_"i <<< ".txt"}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

The large text file is formatted below:

```
Name: X
Description: This does something
Data: 
0
1
//
Name: Y
Description: This does something else
Data: 
2
3
4
5
//
Name: Z
Description: Z record description
Data: 
2
4
//
Name: Zeta
Description: This does something else too
Data: 
5
13
//
```

The desired output is two files containing Named records split by forward slashes.

**File 1**

```
Name: X
Description: This does something
Data: 
0
1
//
Name: Y
Description: This does something else
Data: 
2
3
4
5
//
```

**File 2**

```
Name: Z
Description: Z record description
Data: 
2
4
//
Name: Zeta
Description: This does something else too
Data: 
5
13
//
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
awk -v n=2 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="//\n"; FS=OFS="\n"; c=0} {$1=$1; if(NR%n==1){close(f); f="file_" ++c ".txt"}; print >f}' file
```

`$1=$1` forces `awk` to rebuild current row.

`NR%n` is a modulo operation.

I use `close()` to prevent the maximum possible number of open files from being reached.

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, **OFS**, **RS**, **ORS**, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Thank you Cyrus! This worked well. I appreciate the integration of RS and ORS to identify and separate the records using forward slashes. You are awesome!

Comment: Setting FS and OFS and doing `$1=$1;` is doing nothing but forcing awk to do field splitting (if you don't reference a field in your script then gawk won't split the record into fields) and then forcing it to recompile the record to be what it already was. You could just remove `FS=OFS="\n";`, `c=0`, and `$1=$1` and the script will behave the same way but execute faster.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

`print > "file_"i".txt"` is using an unparenthesized expression on the right side of output redirection which is undefined behavior per POSIX, hence the syntax error. It needs to be `print > ("file_"i".txt")` instead.

FWIW I'd write your script as:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { out="file_" (++i) ".txt" }
    { print > out }
    /^>>/ { close(out); out="file_" (++i) ".txt" }
' Pfam-A.hmm
```

The above will work using any awk.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you're seeking can also be described as `[\n][\/][\/][\n]` (or without the square brackets)

If the file isn't too big, say, within 800MB, consider just reading the full file in, and using `FS = "\n\/\/\n"` .

then field number `$10000` will be the cutoff point you seek.

don't be afraid of large field numbers - mawk2 can easily handle 8-digit or even low-9-digit horizontal field numbers before it starts to sweat a bit.